# Comma or period after "but I disagree" statement

Tags: punctuation

So I have a sentence looking something like this (punctuation removed):
***"People say that rainy days are the worst days _ but I disagree _ I think they're the best of all"***
I'm struggling to figure out what I should replace the underscores with.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single answer to this. Assuming it should be kept as a single sentence rather than changed into two sentences, there are several possibilities.

- People say that rainy days are the worst days---but I disagree; I think they're the best of all.
- People say that rainy days are the worst days; but I disagree---I think they're the best of all.
- People say that rainy days are the worst days but I disagree (I think they're the best of all).
  People say that rainy days are the worst days---but I disagree (I think they're the best of all).
- People say that rainy days are the worst days (but I disagree---I think they're the best of all).
- People say that rainy days are the worst days (but I disagree; I think they're the best of all).
- People say that rainy days are the worst days (but I disagree. I think they're the best of all). [Here, there is arguably a second sentence inside the parentheses. However, parenthetical content doesn't impact the structure of text that surrounds it.]

Stylistically, some of these options---particularly the last three, and certainly the final one---are less common and, depending on the rest of the text, would not be a popular choice. But they are still technically correct. The choice will be subjective and possibly guided by an in-house style guide. The way each variation is read also results in a slightly different cadence, tone of voice, and mental interpretation.

I could have continued with a few more variations but didn't think it would add to my point. (Note that "---" represents an em dash.)